# Python count the number of lines that contain numbers in a text file

Tags: python

Let's say I have this text file :

```
some text
120 130
1847 1853
other text
207 220
text
306 350
some other text
400 435
900 121
125 369
```

I want to count the number of lines that contains numbers after each string so my output will be like :

```
2
1
1
3
```

Here's what I have tried :

```
m=0    
with open('some_txt_file.txt','r') as f:
        for line in f:
                if line.replace(" ","").isdigit():
                    m+=1
                else:
                    m=0
```

But this is giving me a wrong result. How can I code that ?

Comment: You define `c` but never use it, then increment `m` in the loop. This code cannot run, except by fluke where the first line is a string. You need an [mcve]

Comment: Add to that that whitespace (`' '.isdigit()`) is `False`

Comment: I corrected that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you're missing is the fact that each line terminates with `'\n'` which is sabotaging the `.isdigit()` test.  Let's use the same code, but just `.strip()` that line ending out:

```
m = 0
with open('some_txt_file.txt','r') as f: 
    for line in f: 
        if line.strip().replace(" ", "").isdigit(): 
            m += 1 
        else: 
            if m: print(m) 
            m = 0 
    if m: print(m)

# prints:
# 2
# 1
# 1
# 3
```

Comment: How can I store the results in a list of lists if I have a bunch of files to process ?

Comment: Create each list outside the loop, and `.append()` to the list where appropriate.  Try it, then ask a separate question on stackoverflow if there's a specific problem that's blocking your progress.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
m=0   
with open('some_txt_file.txt','r') as f:
    first = True
    for line in f:
        if first and line.strip().replace(' ', '').isdigit():
            continue
        elif first:
            first = False
            continue
        if line.strip().replace(' ', '').isdigit():
            m+=1
        else:
            print(m)
            m=0
    print(m)
```

The `isdigit()` will currently fail as the numbers have spaces in them, so better to check for numbers in the line. This will also work if any lines are not followed by any numbers, which will fail in the other answers since they ignore m==0

Comment: and if the first line is numeric? :)

Comment: I assume we wouldn't care, since the question is asking about the numbers `after` the text, so if it starts with numbers they are irrelevent

Comment: but then you are missing the first count value.

Comment: anyway, no need for the "first check". You can simply switch to the next value in the list: list(f)[1:]

Answer (score 0):

I tried in this way. This works correctly only if the first line is always non numeric:

```
text = """some text
120 130
1847 1853
other text
207 220
text
306 350
some other text
400 435
900 121
125 369"""

lines = text.split("\n")

c = 0
for line in lines[1:]:
    if line[0].isdigit():
        c+=1
    else:
        print(c)
        c=0
print(c)

# 2
# 1
# 1
# 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure about what i will say, i can't test the code bellow but here are the issues i think they remains

Look for readline() fonction
plus, line always be a String, each time your going to test it "else" condition will always be used. Try to cast line before.

```
count = 0 
with open('some_txt_file.txt','r') as f:
line = f.readline()
while line:
    try:
        int(line)
        count++
        line = file.readline()

    except:
          line = file.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work

```
import re

res  = re.findall("[0-9 \n]+",a,re.DOTALL|re.IGNORECASE)

for each in res:
    if each.strip()
        print(len([i for i in each.split("\n") if i]))
```